# Python lambda in C++

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a Python program, in which there's a function that should be able to accept a Python lambda, and then pass to a running C++ program.

I was thinking of using pickle.dumps to serialize the lambda into a string. Then I just pass the string to the C++ program, after which I do deserialization using boost.python and get the lambda in C++. However, I just realized that functions cannot be pickled.

I believe there should be existing solutions that I'm not aware of. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: What do you want to with the lambda in C++? Call it? If so, the easiest way is to use the C API, pass the lambda as a PyObject*, and use PyCall. That has the added benefit that you can use any callable object, not just lambdas.

Comment: @Adam That would be great, and yes I do want to call the lambda in the C++ program. However, while both the python program and the C++ program are running, how should I send the lambda to the C++ program? Or is it some shared-memory method?

Comment: I don't think that there's a "function that should be able to accept a Python lambda". Rather, it will accept anything that is callable, like a lamba, function, class or any object that explicitly supports being called. If you treat it just like a function, you could easily pass it to C++ and call it from there.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks! How can I access this object from C++? I don't understand how to "easily pass it to C++"...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [C API tutorial page](https://docs.python.org/2.7//extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c). The link goes to the section about calling Python functions from C. It sounds like you're new to the C API, so start at the top.

Python does not distinguish between the various types of callable objects. Functions, lambdas, objects that have a `__call__` method are interchangeable as far as the C API is concerned.

I won't copy/paste everything here as it's very well written in the link, but basically you make a Python module in C (or C++, the API works in both). The first example shows you how. Then you can call a C function from Python, and pass it whatever you need to pass it. All Python objects are exposed to C via `PyObject*` pointers, and the C API provides many functions to manipulate the objects, convert to/from C datatypes, and do things like call callable objects.

Wrappers like boost.python and SWIG use this API internally.